# how to turn off jumping by parts when moving (snapping)

Tags: modeling

I accidently somehow enabled jumping when moving objects (when you move an object it moves by short and precise steps) and I don't know how to disable it.

Comment: You mean snapping?

Comment: yes, I think so.

Comment: Check the [wiki](http://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/basics/navigating/introduction.html?highlight=snapping)? (scroll down)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

click on the magnet (looks like a horseshoe) in the 3D view
[image]