# Blender 3D object editor skipping frames

Tags: 3d-view

I started using Blender to learn 3D design. I'm using Blender 2.78. My problem is that when I'm in 3D editor, the editor skips frames. For example, if I want to extrude a finger out of the hand, it won't show me the extrusion until I've dragged it out quite far. Due to this I am unable to select various positions and sizes. This was not happening before. It started when my model got a little bit detailed. 
My specs are:
GPU: Nvidia Geforce 940 MX.
RAM: 8 GB.
CPU: Intel Core i3 6100u 2.3GHz.

Can anyone please tell me how i can fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a snapping option on?

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2834/cursor-is-set-to-move-by-increments-how-to-reset-to-normal (more special case http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35235/how-to-turn-off-jumping-by-parts-when-moving-snapping)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably this happens because you have the snapping option on as shown below. Try to disable it.

[image]